# Dialog with phonegap from webpage

Tags: javascript, cordova, html, inappbrowser

I would like dialog with phonegap api from my webpage, open with InAppBrowser :

browser = window.open("http://my-website.fr/mob_home.php" );

On action in webpage (btn), should I can close the browser from the webpage with listenner or interface javascript.

Thx for any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.addEventListener('loadstop', function () {
    browser.executeScript(code: {
        your code here
    }, function (youCallBackVariable) {
        if (yourCallBackVariable) {
            browser.close();
        }
    });
});
```

this should work, but you can find a more explained solution here:
[Hacky way to return variables](http://www.icenium.com/blog/icenium-team-blog/2013/12/23/cross-window-communication-with-cordova%27s-inappbrowser)